# Why are newlines added to the help under python click

Tags: python

I'm using the [Click Python library](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) to parse the command line arguments.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.option('--opt', default=1, help='Flag for if we want success or failure\n0 = failure\n1 = success')
@click.pass_context
```

When I run my program, for some reason, there's an extra newline between the hyphen and the word "success".  Can anyone tell me why there's a newline added?  I didn't add a newline there.  The new line is after both of the words "failure", which is correct.  However, there should be one after the word success, but for some reason, it comes before the word success.

```
$ ./get_last_successful_build.py --help
Usage: get_last_successful_build.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --opt INTEGER    Flag for if we want success or failure
                   0 - failure
                   1 -
                   success
  --help           Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Click is wrapping your paragraph based on the width of the terminal but not factoring in newlines:

> The default behavior of Click is to rewrap text based on the width of the terminal. In some circumstances, this can become a problem. The main issue is when showing code examples, where newlines are significant.

If you take the whole help string, with the padding that Click itself adds, and remove all newlines, the word `success` ends at character position 81:

```
  --opt INTEGER    Flag for if we want success or failure 0 - failure 1 - success
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
```

If the newlines themselves are included in its calculation that brings us to 83. I'm not sure how wide your terminal is, but 80 columns is a common width.

See if you can [override this with `\b`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/documentation/#preventing-rewrapping) (wrapped for readability):

```
@click.option(
    '--opt',
    default=1,
    help='\b\nFlag for if we want success or failure\n0 = failure\n1 = success'
)
```

> Rewrapping can be disabled on a per-paragraph basis by adding a line with solely the `\b` escape marker in it. This line will be removed from the help text and rewrapping will be disabled.

Comment: Well, this sounds reasonable but it is a little bit strange as why there is still `\n` after "failure" and before "0"? Or if `\n` won't influence how `click` recognize lines, adding `\b` might remove the whole help text.

Comment: @Sraw, I'm not sure exactly how this works, but I think your inline `\n` values are rendered but not considered when Click adds its own newlines. Give it a try and see what happens.